# Will me having spent a long time in school affect my job search?

Tags: job-search

My question is, I have spent a long time in school getting my bachelors. Will my duration in school on my resume affect my application? My situation is I have had health issues that have caused me to take breaks from school and take on a reduced course load. I was supposed to graduate in 2016 but due to these factors I will be graduating in spring 2021. How much will this affect my application. Also is there anyway to reflect my situation on my Resume?

Sorry if question is poor. I will appreciate any advice.

Comment: see also [Impact of time needed to go through university on a resume](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/97952/168)

Comment: @gnat Thanks for the links. Guess I didn't look hard enough.

Answer (score 1):

> Will my duration in school on my resume affect my application?

Yes. It's fairly unusual and everything unusual attracts attention.

> How much will this affect my application.

Quite a bit, I'm afraid. 1 or 2 years over target won't raise an eyebrow but 5 years is a lot. You will be competing with other candidates that finished on time and are considerably younger.

> Also is there anyway to reflect my situation on my Resume?

Of course.

In any case you will to answer the question is almost guaranteed to come up: "Why did it take you so long to get your bachelors degrees?" Make sure you have a good story. Write it  down, revised and rehearse it. The story should be truthful and accurate but it should also show you in the best possible light and focus on your strengths and achievements along the way.

Your resume should on your strengths and show what you can bring to the party. Maybe you have more maturity, you learned certain skills or behaviors during this time, you've learned how to deal with hardship and obstacles, etc. It needs to include enough of your story to make the 5 extra years plausible.

Ideally, your resume should also include an explanation of why whatever caused the delay will not affect your fit and expected performance for the job. If it's a health issue, perhaps you have recovered. If your health issues are still an issue and you require specific accommodations at work, you should talk to a medical professional and someone knowledgeable with your local labor laws & regulations.